# UITextfield.Text color is not working despite being set in code and attributes inspector - Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uistoryboard

I am trying to set the text color of two textfields on my UIStoryboard. I have attempted to set the color in both the attributes inspector and the code. Regardless, every time I run the simulator, the text color is clear and just takes on the Main Views background color.

Below is my code for setting the text color. The color is set within an array called MemeTextAttributes and the array is then set as the value for the text_field_name.defaultTextAttributes in the viewDidLoad().

```
let memeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
     NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.black,
     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple,
     NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
     NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: 2.0
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.topTxtField.delegate = self
    self.bottomTxtField.delegate = self
    topTxtField.text = "TOP"
    topTxtField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    bottomTxtField.text = "BOTTOM"
    bottomTxtField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    topTxtField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    bottomTxtField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
}
```

[image: Color being set in the attributes inspector]
[image: Image of simulator with both textFields]

Comment: The attributed text is over ruling it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Are you referring to the setting of the color in the attributes inspector and in the code conflicting? If so, I set the color in the code and in the attributed on separate occasions, as in I tested them separately and it still did not work.

Comment: I'm saying that the attributed text carries the formatting information which will be used, which ignores the properties of the text field

Comment: Do you see the color changes in storyboard?

Comment: Ok just set the color in textField.textColor and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Set either stroke color or Foreground color because stroke is overlapping foreground color. Thanks